# Download csv schedule from https URL using Python

Tags: python, csv, https

I cannot seem to locate a URL path to the CSV file so as to try and use python csv.reader, requests, urllib, or pandas.
Here is the webpage: https://www.portconnect.co.nz/#/vessel-schedule/expected-arrivals
Am I on the right track?
Could you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

normally it should be quite easy by using pandas if you only had the direct link to the csv file. With the provided url, I could download the csv from https://www.portconnect.co.nz/568a8a10-3379-4096-a1e8-76e0f1d1d847

```
import pandas as pd
portconnecturl = "https://www.portconnect.co.nz/568a8a10-3379-4096-a1e8-76e0f1d1d847"

print("Downloading data from portconnect...")
df_csv = pd.read_csv(portconnecturl)
print(df_csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

.csv files can't be integrated inside a webpage,hence you won't get a webpage+.csv file url. You will have to download it exclusively and read it in your code. Else if will need to use web **scraping** and **scrape** the details that you want using beautiful soup or selenium python modules.

Comment: FYI it’s scrape and scraping not scrap or scrapping